# Magento Varien_Data_Collections: when is SQL query executed

Tags: database, magento, collections

I`d like to know how Magento internally processes database calls on varien_data_collections. For example: One of my models returns a data collection to a Block. Additional where clauses are added via Layout XML blocks and afterwards appended to the returned data collection from te model.

Does this mean database calls are made twice? One on the initial `$model->getCollection()` method and one on `$collection->addFieldToFilter('x',array('eq'=>'y'))` in the Block.

Or does Magento make the SQL call on the iteraror?

See my situation below:

**Model Class:**

```
<?php

Class X_Y_Model_A extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract{
    ...

    public function getRelatedItems(){
        return $this->getCollection()
            ->addFieldtoFilter('id',array('eq'=>$this->getId()));
    }
}

?>
```

**Block Class:**

```
<?php

Class X_Y_Block_A extends Mage_Core_Block_Template{

    private $limit = 5;

    public function setDbLimit($limit){
        $this->limit = (int)$limit;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getDbLimit(){
        return $this->limit;
    }

    public function getRelatedItems(){
        $_collection = Mage::getModel('xy/a')->getRelatedItems();
        $_collection->setPageSize($this->getDbLimit());
        return $_collection;
    }

}

?>
```

**Layout XML file**

```
<layout>
    ...
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="xy/a" name="xy" as="xy" template="xy/related.phtml">
            <action method="setDbLimit"><limit>2<limit></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</layout>
```

**View .phtml**

```
<?php 
    // xy/related.phtml
    $_relatedItems = $this->getRelatedItems();

    if($_relatedItems->getSize()>0){
        foreach($_relatedItems as $_relatedItem){
            // HTML Output
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento uses lazy-loading and only performs the query when it really needs data from the resultset. So as long as you don't use a result, you can keep adding conditionals or filters without really executing the query.

Comment: So basicly this means to query is not executed until the for loop is called in the template?

Comment: Uhm... Not exactly... As soon as something from the result is needed. In a lot of cases, this is as soon as the iteration over the resultset starts. This is not the case when for example the number of returned elements is required before the loop (for example for pagination purposes or the likes)